# php simple contact form - stop submit on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

The following PHP form works without any issues other than on refresh. If a user hits the refresh button after submitting the form, it re-submits the form.

Is there a way to use PHP or Jquery to stop the form re-submitting after refreshing the page?

I know in PHP there should be a way with Session, but I am not sure how.

**contact.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.error_message{color:#cc0000;}
.form1{}
.form2{display:none;}
#succsess_page h1{background:url('http://example.com/ok.png')left no-repeat;padding-left:40px;color:#45a015; }
</style>
<h1>This is a simple contact form</h1>

<?php
//fields
        $link_address   = 'contact.php'; // page to redirect to
        $honeypot   = '';
        $error      = '';
        $name       = 'Name';
        $email      = 'Email';
        $comments   = 'Message';

        if(isset($_POST['contactus'])) {

        $honeypot   = $_POST['email_confirm'];
        $name       = $_POST['name'];
        $email      = $_POST['email'];
        $comments   = $_POST['comments'];

// honeypot
if($honeypot)
  exit(1);


//error messages
        if(trim($name) == 'Name') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Name</div>';
        } else if(trim($name) == '') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Name</div>';

        } else if(trim($email) == 'Email') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Email</div>';
        } else if(trim($email) == '') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Email</div>';

        } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">Need a valid email</div>';

        } else if(trim($comments) == 'Message') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">A Message is required</div>';
        } else if(trim($comments) == '') {
            $error = '<div class="error_message">A Message is required</div>';

        }
        if($error == '') {
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $comments = stripslashes($comments);
        }
//email address
        $address = "email@example.com";
//email message     
        $e_subject = 'Web Message from: ' . $name . '.';
        $e_body = "From:    $name\nEmail:   $email \r\n\nMessage:\n$comments\n\n\n";

        $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;
        if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
        {
//success html page response
         echo "<div id='succsess_page'>";
         echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
         echo "<p>Thank you. The following was sent to us. <br/><br/>$name<br/><br/>$email<br/><br/>$comments</p>";
         echo "<a href='$link_address'>CLOSE THIS MESSAGE</a>";
         echo "</div>";
         } else echo "Error. Mail not sent";
        }
    }
        if(!isset($_POST['contactus']) || $error != '') // Do not edit.
    {

?>
        <?php echo $error; ?>
<!--form-->
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">

<p class="form1">Name: <input  name="name" type="text" id="name"  size="30" class="input1" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="toUpper(this.value); if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Name'; }" value="Name" /></p>

<p class="form1">Email: <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" class="input2" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email'; }" value="Email" /></p>
<p class="form2">Confirm Email: <input name="email_confirm" type="text" id="email_confirm" size="30" value="<?php echo $email_confirm; ?>" /></p>

<p class="form1">Message: <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Message') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Message'; }" value="Message"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea></p>

<p class="form1"><input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit" /></p>

</form>
<!--end form-->

<?php }

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.
return(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,12})$/",$email));
}

?>

<!------- capitalize first letter Name input ---->
<script>
function toUpper(mystring) {
var sp = mystring.split(' ');
var wl=0;
var f ,r;
var word = new Array();
for (i = 0 ; i < sp.length ; i ++ ) {
f = sp[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
r = sp[i].substring(1);
word[i] = f+r;
}
newstring = word.join(' ');
document.getElementById('name').value = newstring;
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to dump such a huge wall of code to replicate the problem? You might want to read [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see if you can trim this down to a shorted example that demonstrates the same behavior.

Comment: @Aiken I thought this is pretty simple. Where am I replicating? I made it pretty simple, send form, show user what they submitted. Which on the page they can print it if they like. I would be interested in what you can show me. I am always looking to simplify. thanks

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything _wrong_ with your code (other than the stated problem about which you asked this question), what I'm saying is that a good amount of it is probably irrelevant to the question being asked. As a somewhat silly and simplified example: Imagine I'm asking someone how to put on a T-shirt. Does the person I'm asking really need to know the color, brand, size and material of the T-shirt to answer my question?

Comment: @Aiken. Gotcha. I understand now. The reason for all the code is if it gets answered and fixed, others will have something to use or modify themselves. Try to pass on the learning to everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the form has been submitted correctly run the following code:

```
header("Location :contact.php?msg=success");
```

This will redirect the user back to the contact form with an condition allowing for a message to be displayed.

```
if($_REQUEST['msg']){
 echo "Contact Form Submitted Successfully!!";
}
```

If they hit refresh it will just bring up a successful message while displaying the contact form again.

Update:

```
if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
    {
       header("Location: contact.php?msg=success");
    }else{
       header("Location: contact.php?msg=error");
    }
```

Then for displaying:

```
<?php if($_REQUEST['msg']=="success"){
    echo "Success Message Here.";
}elseif($_REQUEST['msg']=="error"){
    echo "Error Message Here."
}
<!--form-->
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
```

Comment: where would I put the code? before <?php echo $error;?>

Comment: The header location will go where the form submit is successful. below <?php echo $error;?> you can say the condition statement.

Comment: now it is not showing up. Since I cant post it here, I posted it on JSFIDDLE at http://jsfiddle.net/vw6qLkpz/, I know PHP does not work on JSFIDDLE, I just posted it there so you can see what I have.

Comment: You need a condition above your form as I posted to handle the response message

Comment: That works. Thanks for helping me out and having patience with me.

Comment: Sweet no worries any time!